# A MySQL query that will match any combination of an array

Tags: mysql, match, combinations

I have a series of words in a string/array which are a combination of a state/province, city and  a business name.

The state/province is always the first value in the list.

Both the business names and the cities can be a single or multiple words.

For example: 
ca|anaheim|khs|ice|arena = KHS Ice Arena in Anaheim, CA

ca|anaheim|the|rinks|anaheim = The Rinks Anaheim, Anaheim CA

ca|los|angeles|pickwick|skating|rink

ny|manhatten|trump|center|skating|rink

qc|fond|du|lac|blue|line|family|ice|center

qc|fond|du|lac|spectrum|roller|skating|rink

There are more cities than businesses so I imagine it would most efficient to first find a matches that exist among the business names.  If none, end.  However if a match or matches is found among any combination of words in the array than loop through the combination or words to find a match or matches where the business name exists within a particular city.

As for tables and rows I have two tables joined on the zip combination:

tbl_location.location_id, tbl_location.location_name, tbl_location.location_zip

tbl_postal.location_city, tbl_postal.location_state, tbl.postal.zip, tbl_postal.location_lat, tbl_postal.location_lon

I need to return:

tbl_location.location_id, tbl_location.location_name, tbl_postal.location_city, tbl_postal.location_state, tbl.postal.zip, tbl_postal.location_lat, tbl_postal.location_lon

What would be the most efficient way to do this?  I'm stumped.   Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: You broke first normal form by putting multiple values in the same field.  The efficient way to search this type of thing is to not do that.  You should make a separate table just for this field, and create one record in that table for each element of the array.

Comment: Thanks - understood - hence why I'm trying to do this.  I'm attempting to unwind code written by a developer 15 years ago...

Comment: Well, I figured out that it's even worse than I thought as sometimes cities which should be separated with a space or a - are not... So I think I'm going take the long way around the block and set up a PDO and do a levenshtein/metaphone search looping through the cities first as 1, 2, 3 and then 4 pieces and then do the same for the business names.  Fun times.

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this other than the hard way.  Honestly, it might be easiest to pull it into Excel, split the columns on the pipe, and try to use sorting and filtering to categorize the table, then built queries from that.  As presented, the data is only usable by looking at it and manipulating it by hand.

Comment: I split the array up into pieces and then am using levenshtein/metaphone to loop through the various combinations of pieces to first find a match on the business name and then the city or vice versa.  It's working great so far.  I'd paste the code but it's pretty ugly right now.  The seed for the idea came from here: http://codepen.io/terf/post/creating-a-search-engine-with-php-pdo-mysql